# matplotlib: deliberately block code execution pending a GUI event

Tags: python, events, numpy, event-handling, matplotlib

Is there some way that I can get matplotlib to block code execution pending a `matplotlib.backend_bases.Event`?

I've been working on some classes for interactively drawing lines and polygons inside matplotlib figures, following [these examples](http://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html). What I'd really like to do is block execution until I'm done editing my polygon, then get the final positions of the vertices - if you're familiar with MATLAB, I'm basically trying to replicate the `position = wait(roihandle)` syntax, for example [here](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/images/ref/impoly.html#bq_wyu3).

I suppose I could set some class attribute of my interactive polygon object when a keypress occurs, then repeatedly poll the object in my script to see if the event has occurred yet, but I was hoping there would be a nicer way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, that was easier than I thought it would be! For those who are interested I found a solution using `figure.canvas.start_event_loop()` and `figure.canvas.stop_event_loop()`.

Here's a simple example:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

class FigEventLoopDemo(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, num='Event loop demo')
        self.clickme = self.ax.text(0.5, 0.5, 'click me',
                                    ha='center', va='center',
                                    color='r', fontsize=20, picker=10)

        # add a callback that triggers when the text is clicked
        self.cid = self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', self.on_pick)

        # start a blocking event loop
        print("entering a blocking loop")
        self.fig.canvas.start_event_loop(timeout=-1)

    def on_pick(self, event):

        if event.artist is self.clickme:

            # exit the blocking event loop
            self.fig.canvas.stop_event_loop()
            print("now we're unblocked")
```