# How to release matplolib execution without closing window

Tags: python, user-interface, matplotlib

I want to show a series of images using `imshow()` and a `for` loop, but I want to wait for user input on the image (not on terminal) before continuing.  The following does work but it requires closing the window, which is not optimal as my for loop has over a thousand iterations.  How can I put a plt.clf() and unblock temporarily until next loop.

```
x, y, z = sp.mgrid[0:10, 0:100, 0:100]

for img in x:
    f = plt.figure()
    def onkey(event):
        print("pressed {}".format(event))
        plt.close(f)
    f.canvas.mpl_connect("key_press_event", onkey)
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.show()
    print("continuing")
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this turned out to be a repeated question:

[matplotlib: deliberately block code execution pending a GUI event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14325844/matplotlib-deliberately-block-code-execution-pending-a-gui-event)

It is the mix of `f.canvas.start_event_loop(timeout=-1)` and `f.canvas.stop_event_loop()` that does the trick.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
plt.ion()
plt.show()
```

before the loop, and remove `plt.close()` & `plt.show()` inside the loop.

To block the loop until a press event occurred add:

```
f.canvas.start_event_loop(timeout=-1)
```

inside the loop

Comment: The problem is that I do need to block the code and wait for the user interaction to continue... your solution does not block the code at all :S

Comment: hmmm, still no good. I do not want to unblock the code for each key press, It depends on what is pressed to see whether I unblock it or not. Say, with 'f' key I unblock, with 'a' key, I don't.

Comment: Well, how you did it until now?

Comment: I have done it as in my example above, but that closes the window... the second it takes for the window to come back in the next loop is very cumbersome when there are over iterations :S.. I would like to be able to issue an "unblock for this time only" command. Thanks!

Comment: You can check the pressed key inside your `onkey` function and block again for some condition.